# Laplacian of a potential. Correct use of Index gymnastics and notation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, laplacian

Currently working my way through *[Gravity Newtonian, Post-Newtonian, Relativistic](http://www.cambridge.org/au/academic/subjects/physics/cosmology-relativity-and-gravitation/gravity-newtonian-post-newtonian-relativistic?format=HB&isbn=9781107032866#bKF45GifOmulh1h5.97)* - Poisson and Will (2014) and I've stumbled upon a potential issue with my memory of vector calc in index notation.

**Context**

---

I've got an equation which takes the following form

$$ \rho ( \partial_t \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{v}) = \rho \nabla U - \nabla p, \tag{1} \label{eq:maineq} $$

where mass density, pressure, velocity vector field and Newtonian gravitational potential for a fluid element are given by $\rho, p, \mathbf{v}$ and $U$ respectively. Usual notation is used i.e. $\partial_t\equiv\partial/\partial t$ etc. etc.

Now, in terms of a fluid element comprised of a continuous matter distribution, the Newtonian gravitational potential satisfies Poisson's equation, namely

$$ \nabla^2U = -4\pi G \rho. \tag{2} $$

We can express the first term on the RHS of Eq. (\ref{eq:maineq}) as the following

$$ \rho \partial_j U =  -\frac{1}{4 \pi G} \nabla^2 U \partial_j U. $$

where $\partial_j U \equiv \nabla U$. The steps that follow is where the issue lies.

**Question**

---

We have $ -\frac{1}{4 \pi G} \nabla^2 U \partial_j U$ which can be expressed as the following

$$ -\frac{1}{4 \pi G} (\partial_k\partial_k U) \partial_j U. \tag{3} \label{eq:laplacegrad}$$

In light of the comments below can someone explain the steps that Poisson and Will have taken to arrive at the following:

$$\rho \partial_j U = -\frac{1}{4 \pi G} \partial_k  \left( \partial_j U \partial_k U - \frac{1}{2} \delta^{jk} \partial_i U \partial_i U \right). \tag{4} \label{eq:derive}$$

With regards the rules of the site. To see my (incorrect) attempt, it can be seen in a previously edited version of the question.

See below for answer.

Comment: Equation (3) seems to be missing at least one $U$. And $\partial_k \partial_j u$ is certainly not $\nabla u \cdot \nabla u$. please double check your copying.

Comment: @WillieWong you are right. they were minor typos. they should be fixed now.

Comment: The subsequent lines also have typos. Please fix them too.

Comment: Incidentally: $\nabla^2 U \partial_j U = \partial_k (\partial_k U \partial_j U) - \frac12 \partial_j |\nabla U|^2 \neq \partial_k(\partial_k U \partial_j U)$ in general. And $|\nabla U|^2 \neq \partial_k U \partial_j U$.

Comment: @WillieWong I was missing a fair few potentials! I think they are corrected now. But they are equivalent for $j=k$ or not?

Comment: You are employing an implicit summation convention. $k$ repeated means that you are summing over $k$. It is meaningless to say "$j = k$" when the former is an explicit index and the latter is a dummy index that is being summed.

Comment: @WillieWong I may need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Winther I've edited the question because I seemed to be quite far off. I thought my reasoning was correct with the chain rule on $|\nabla U|^2$ for $j=k$ but I seem to have been using an incorrect tool in index gymnastics according to WillieWong above.

Comment: @Winther Fantastic! Okay I've got it working. If you would like to post an answer I will gladly accept!

Comment: @Winther I've updated question with what you have suggested but, again, place a short answer with the above comment and I will accept. Cheers!

Comment: A better idea is for you to cut out the answer you have added to the question and paste it as an answer below (and you can accept your own answer). This is a perfectly fine thing to do. I don't have anything to add to what you have written which looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer ( thanks to the comments above)**

---

To summarise the comments above and the steps necessary for the correct derivation, we may begin by noticing

$$(\nabla^2 U) \partial_j U \equiv (\partial_k \partial_k U) \partial_j U.$$

Apply the product rule to $\partial_k (\partial_k U \partial_j U)$ giving

$$ \partial_k (\partial_k U \partial_j U)= (\partial_k\partial_k U)\partial_j U + \partial_k U (\partial_k \partial_j U), $$

where we may deduce

$$ (\partial_k \partial_k U) \partial_j U = \partial_k (\partial_k U \partial_j U) - \partial_k U (\partial_k \partial_j U). $$

Next, notice the relation

$$ \partial_k U (\partial_k \partial_j U) \equiv \frac{1}{2} \partial_j |\nabla U|^2. $$

Which can be seen by performing the chain rule

$$ \frac{1}{2} \partial_j |\nabla U|^2 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \partial_k U (\partial_k \partial_j U). $$

Finally, we can express $\partial_j \equiv \partial_k \delta^{k}_{j}$ and then piecing together allows one to successfully derive the relation given in the question above.